# Cannot execute code from a freed script error on IE 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, iframe

I have a use case where I subscribe / listen to a topic on every `iframe`, now occasionally this `iframe` will be removed and replaced with a new `iframe`.

Also, I don't have a clean way to unsubscribe to the initial subscriber on the removed `iframe`.

In Chrome, when an event is published on the removed `iframe` subscription, it's caught in the `try / catch`block, however in IE10 it outright throws an error "Cannot execute on a freed script"

**iframe 1 (Which will be removed from the DOM)**

```
subscribe("event-topic", (event) {
   try { ... }
   catch(ex) { ... }
})
```

**iframe 2**

```
subscribe("event-topic", (event) {
   try { ... }
   catch(ex) { ... }
})
```

**Main Application**

```
publish("event-topic");
```

Now, as an example, the 1st `iframe` is removed and 2nd `iframe` is added. The main application starts to publish the event. This publish results in both the subscribers callbacks being invoked. Now since the 1st `iframe` is not there anymore, Chrome sends this to the `try/catch` block in the subscribe callback while IE throws an error.

I tried to add the unsubscription mechanism when the `iframe` is removed but that's resulting in a lot of junk code which I would want to avoid as much as possible.

Did anyone resolve this issue or is there a workaround to get IE to behave the same way as Chrome? Like a polyfill?

Comment: What is `subscribe`? What mechanism is being used here?

Comment: It's almost like a publish / subscribe mechanism, close to `addEventListener` but for custom events.

Comment: Without knowing the details of the mechanism you're using, I don't see how we can help you.

Comment: can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). From your description, it seems that you'd better to check whether the iframe is exist or not before taking action.